# Xamarin studio storyboards blank

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uistoryboard, xamarin-studio

I've been working through some Xamarin.iOS courses and have come across a recurring issue. It seems that every time I close Xamarin Studio and open it later the storyboards I have created are blank. The document outline shows that there should be views to display but the storyboard is blank:

[image: Blank storyboard]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: They might be mislocated, try selecting a view (list on the right-hand side) and change its position.

Comment: I got it! I changed the view as dropdown from Generic to iPhone 6 and all my views appeared. I wouldn't have thought to check those other options if I hadn't been following your advice in trying to change the position of the views, hence the +1.

Answer (score 1):

For some people who might be struggling still, if you found the storyboard is blank, check connection with mac. Moreover, you need to add view controller which located in tool box. Just drag it into the storyboard file you are viewing.